# Upgrade from Sitecore 9.0 to Sitecore 9.2

Tags: sitecore, upgrade, sitecore9

I am trying to upgrade Sitecore 9.0 to Sitecore 9.2. Couldn't find any specific way except first upgrading to Sitecore 9.0.2 and then proceed further. But, this way getting many errors related with config file. Is there any other way to upgrade directly to 9.2 verion? Any help would be a highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: better to ask this question on - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is your project helix?

When I approach a Sitecore upgrade I am sure to remove all unmodified default configuration files from the solution and where a default config file has been modified, I will move those changes to a patch file.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative method to 'upgrade' which I often look to is to spin up a clean install of the newer version and then migrate my old code into a new solution which will already have all the latest configs/ Sitecore base code in place.

Doing this means you can just patch your custom app config settings and ensure the Sitecore dependencies in your solution are the newer version which can often be a cleaner/simpler way to go.

There are a couple of things to consider before doing this however, such as whether you need to keep your data in XDB etc. as it would mean that you may need to look at migrating it which can be a pain and since you are looking at 9.0 to 9.2, you'd have additional services to consider as well such as Identity and may need to account for that kind of thing too.